# How do I determine wiring colors for ceiling fan?

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I'm trying to install several ceiling fans for our newly built house. I've noticed the wires have a ground (metal wire), white (assume hot), black (neutral), and a red wire. What's the red wire for? I know there's a wall switch for the fan.

Is one of the white/red for the switch and the other for always on (hot) for the fan light? Is there a building standard for the red color?

The ceiling fan has the following wires; white (hot), black (neutral), blue (light) and green (ground wire).

Adding Country/Location: USA, Florida

[image]

The ceiling fan unit has a fan and a light. So, I'm assuming I should connect the fan in a way so that the light can be turned on without having to turn on the wall switch.

```
Black - Black
Red - Blue
White - White
```

Comment: Could you add which country are you in? In US black=hot and white=neutral, so it's better to have your country information so you won't get misleading info.

Comment: Added. Country: USA. House was built in Florida.

Comment: Your assumed way is usually correct, just to add green - copper. But are you sure you want "light can be turned on without having to turn on the wall switch"? The red wire from the ceiling is usually the switch-controlled hot, so if you connect red-blue then the wall switch would control the light.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the wiring diagram for the fan? And do you have a tool to check the voltage at the wires (DMM, non-contact pen type, etc)? From white (neutral) to hot (black and red?) you should have 120vac either all the time or when you flip the switch.